# How can I make this code with enumerations generic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am creating the wrapper POCO classes for ENUM in Entity Framework 4 as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4). I have created the wrapper for the enum as follows

```
public class PriorityWrapper
    {
        private gender _t;
        public int Value
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)_t;
            }
            set
            {
                _t = (gender)value;
            }
        }
        public gender EnumValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _t;
            }
            set
            {
                _t = value;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator PriorityWrapper(gender p)
        {
            return new PriorityWrapper { EnumValue = p };
        }

        public static implicit operator gender(PriorityWrapper pw)
        {
            if (pw == null) return gender.Male;
            else return pw.EnumValue;
        }
    }
```

But I also have other ENUM apart from gender  as mentioned above. Can I use generics here so I can use the same code for all ENUM occurrences.

I am new to generics, so need help from experts.

Comment: Answers here are old, this is now supported, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/1pvNYK

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use enums as generic constraints, instead you can use.

```
 public  class EnumWrapper<T>
    {
        public static int Num = 1;
        private T _t;

        public T EnumValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _t;
            }
            set
            {
                _t = value;
            }
        }

        public void Assign<U>(U inn) where U : struct, T
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
            {
                EnumValue = inn;
            }


        }
    }
```

and invoke it like this

```
           var agen = new EnumWrapper<gender>();
            gender g=new gender() ;
            agen.Assign (g);
```

**EDIT:** Assign() is a dummy method. My intention was to show how to use enum as generic constraint.

Comment: doesn't make sense. Why would one do agen.Assign(gender.Male) when he can do agen.EnumValue = gender.Male? OP needs ability to convert enum from/to integers.

Comment: @VinayC, yes you are right, it doesnt make any sense, OP is actually asked how to make enum bound generic class. SO i just created a dummy class. My intention was to show him how to use enum as generic constraint....

Comment: @ Ramesh - What if I need to return the default value of Enum from wrapper itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have generic conversion operators. So, there can't be exact generic equivalent for above code. Besides, one cannot mention enum as generic type constraint, so casting within property implementation is also not possible (or may need some other constraint (possibly interface) to work that may result in boxing/unboxing). In short, IMO, having generic solution with reasonable performance may not be feasible.

I would suggest that you try using code generation (look at T4 templates) for creating your wrapper classes. T4 is pretty simple - refer here for few links: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx